# Passport js OIDC strategy not calling the next middleware

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, openid-connect

I am trying to perform authentication and authorization using passport js. I am using OIDC for authentication and trying to perform my own authorization in the code.

I have succeeded in completing the OIDC flow and I am able to establish a session. I am having issues calling my authorization middleware code after the OIDC authentication flow completes.

```
app.js

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.authenticate('session'));
```

```
routes.js

app.use("/callback", callback)
```

```
callback.js

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('oidc', {
        successRedirect: '/profile',
        failureRedirect: '/exit'
      })(req, res, next);
}, (req, res, next) => {
  // Write my authorization code
});
```

The `Write my authorization code` is never getting called. How do I call my authorization code after the OIDC flow completes?

One way I could think of is to create a new endpoint that does authorization and point `successRedirect: '/authorization'` to it but that will end up create a new endpoint which I dont want to do.

I tried searching the passport js documentation but I am not able to find a way to do this.